# How search files in a specific folder by names that I have in a column and return their URL to a spreadsheet, each one in its specific row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My goal is to add the URL shareable links (specific PDF documents stored in G Drive) to all the individual cells in a column in google sheet depending on the document's name. Any script that I find search but not considering that I need each one in a specif row.

**- I have the all the names in a column 
- each row has its pdf file 
- all files are in a specif folder in google drive**

**Does anyone have a code that may help me here?**

[I add an image from the spreadsheet to show what I have and where I'm trying to add the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51MWu.png)

[image]

THANK YOU!

### PS: I'm pretty new on this (google scripts stuff ) I really appreciate any help.

---

MORE ABOUT THE SITUATION 
This is the first script (a create document using data from a spreadsheet that works perfectly well, but with this, I do not know how to add a function that returns the URL ...

> > > > > > > > >

```html
    function createDocument4  () {
  
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET ID, 'RANGE');
  var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET ID, 'RANGE');
  var templateId = 'ADDED TEMPLATE DOC ID ';
  
  for(var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length; i++){
    
    var Text 1 = tactics.values[i][0];
    var text 2 = tactics.values[i][1];
    var text 3 = tactics.values[i][2];

    
    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    
    //Rename the copied file
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(Text 1+'_'+text 2+'_'+text 3+'_'+'example');
    
    //Get the document body as a variable
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
    
    //Insert the supplier name
    body.replaceText('{{ Text 1 }}', Text 1);
    body.replaceText('{{ Text 2 }}', Text 2);
    body.replaceText('{{ Text 3 }}', text 3);

    DocumentApp.openById(documentId).saveAndClose();

    //Make PDF copy at Drive Root
    var docFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).getParents().next().getId();
    var docName = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getName();
    docblob = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getAs('application/pdf');
    docblob.setName(docName + ".pdf");
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
    var fileId = file.getId();
    moveFileId(fileId, docFolder);
  
function moveFileId(fileId, toFolderId) {
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
   var source_folder = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next();
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID')
   folder.addFile(file);
   source_folder.removeFile(file);
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are the names in the first column coming from? If you already have them in some kind of variable, you should be able to loop through them and find the corresponding file/link to put in the next cell over.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering @RGreenstreet! :) 
From column A to G is a kind of manual addition (so far). 
I have a script that generates a document using this data. When I create, I know what texts from this sheet that I used to create the document name. Column H is a CONCATENATE formula. 
I wasn't able to keep everyone in the same script. 
But know, I don't know how to complement this search and add the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out what the sheet name is but perhaps this is what you want.

```
function createDocument4() {
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET ID', 'RANGE');
  var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET ID', 'RANGE');
  var templateId = 'ADDED TEMPLATE DOC ID ';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openbyid('id');
  var sh=ss.getSheets()[0];//I dont really know what the sheet is so I guess the first sheet on the left                                            
  var startRow=2;
  for(var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length; i++){
    var Text 1 = tactics.values[i][0];
    var text 2 = tactics.values[i][1];
    var text 3 = tactics.values[i][2];
    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    //Rename the copied file
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(Text 1+'_'+text 2+'_'+text 3+'_'+'example');
    //Get the document body as a variable
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
    //Insert the supplier name
    body.replaceText('{{ Text 1 }}', Text 1);
    body.replaceText('{{ Text 2 }}', Text 2);
    body.replaceText('{{ Text 3 }}', text 3);
    DocumentApp.openById(documentId).saveAndClose();
    //Make PDF copy at Drive Root
    var docFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).getParents().next().getId();
    var docName = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getName();
    docblob = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getAs('application/pdf');
    docblob.setName(docName + ".pdf");
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
    var fileId = file.getId();
    moveFileId(fileId, docFolder);
    sh.getRange(i+2,9).setValue(file.getUrl());//adding the url to the spreadsheet
  }
}

function moveFileId(fileId, toFolderId) {
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
   var source_folder = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next();
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID')
   folder.addFile(file);
   source_folder.removeFile(file);
}
```